# How to redirect to two diffenrent domains with nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have a domain example.com and I have 2 million visits everyday. There is no website content for this domain, I only `redirect(302)` it to other domain to get my promotion fee.

But I don't want all these 2 million user to visit the same website, maybe for 1 million of them, I will redirect to aol.com, for another million, I will redirect to bestbuy.com.

How to config my `nginx` to redirect the to different domain? If there is something like "`ip_hash`", it would be better!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [split_clients](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html) like this:

```
split_clients "${remote_addr}AAA" $destination {
              50%                 aol.com;
              50%                 bestbuy.com;
}

server {
    server_name example.com;
    return 302 http://$destination/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky and there might be a cleaner way -- but you could use the [random index module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRandomIndexModule) to pick two files from a directory, each file containing a [meta refresh with a delay of zero](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html) to different URLs.

So your nginx config would contain

```
location / {
    random_index on;
}
```

and the document root would contain two files (say `aol.com.html` and `bestbuy.com.html`) containing something like

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    
  <head>      
    <title>example.com</title>      
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://aol.com/'" />    
  </head>    
  <body> 
    <p>This page has moved to a <a href="http://aol.com/">
      aol.com</a>.</p> 
  </body>  
</html>
```

Browsers that support meta refresh will redirect to the URL in the meta tag immediately, so users will see the message for a very short time (if at all).